# Using \mathfrak in tikz: \mathfrak allowed only in math mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm trying to make a presentation using `beamer`, and I'm mostly copying
from already compiled `.tex` file (using the documentclass `memoir`). But I got this error:

```
\mathfrak allowed
only in math mode.
```

When I remove the tikz part, the problem disappears.
The code is below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsopn}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Vir}{Vir}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ind}{Ind}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Der}{Der}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Witt}{Witt}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Centralna proširenja Liejevih algebri}
  Centralno proširenje Liejeve algebre $\mathfrak{g}$ je kratki egzaktni niz
Liejevih algebri:
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzcd}
    0 \arrow{r} 
    &\mathfrak a \arrow{r}{\iota}  
    &\hat{\mathfrak{g}} \arrow{r}{\pi} &\mathfrak{g} \arrow{r} 
    &0
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

takav da je $\iota(\mathfrak a) \subseteq Z(\hat{\mathfrak g})$.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to catcode trickery used in `tikz-cd` and the way that `beamer` treats frames, you need the `ampersand replacement` key for the `tikz-cd` diagram:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Vir}{Vir}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ind}{Ind}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Der}{Der}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Witt}{Witt}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Centralna proširenja Liejevih algebri}
  Centralno proširenje Liejeve algebre $\mathfrak{g}$ je kratki egzaktni niz
Liejevih algebri:
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    0 \arrow{r} 
    \&\mathfrak a \arrow{r}{\iota}  
    \&\hat{\mathfrak{g}} \arrow{r}{\pi} \&\mathfrak{g} \arrow{r} 
    \&0
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{center}

takav da je $\iota(\mathfrak a) \subseteq Z(\hat{\mathfrak g})$.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

No need to explicitly load `amsmath` or `amsopn` with `beamer`.

Comment: This is really nice. I also encounter similar issues. Is "\usepackage{physics}, \usepackage{txfonts}" crucial in your answer?